# I'm getting error when running start-yarn.sh

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I'm getting error when running start-yarn.sh

```
start-yarn.sh   
starting yarn daemons   
starting resourcemanager, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/yarn-root-resourcemanager-Web.out   
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/yarn-root-nodemanager-Web.out      
localhost: Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager
```

#### Bashrc

environment variable

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_101
export JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_101/jre
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_101/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_101/jre/bin
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

#### yarn-site.xml

```xml
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
```

Comment: please place yarn-site.xml

Comment: Update your post with config parameters